# Ruby refactoring a hash loop method return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have code like thus (and I often run into this sort of method signature, the noob that I am coming from java):

```
  def totals
    t = 0
    @data.each do |k, v|
      t += v['totals'].to_i
    end
    t
  end
```

`@data` is a hash of hashes, each internal hash value has a `totals` key. As you can see, I am summing up all the totals.

Could this be simplified or programmed in a different style (I am sure! This is RUBY afterall)? Why do I need to instantiate `t`? Couldn't I return `t` directly from the each loop without a last conditional?

It just does not feel clean! *OH wait! I just remembered blocks*, but I'll wait for your answers ...

**UPDATE:**

The data structure is as such:

```
{ typeA: { items: [], totals: "10" },  typeB: { items: [], totals: "23" }}
```

*I am using Rails! So Rails specific functions would also be great if they extend beyond the vanilla Ruby stack!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've indicated that you are using Ruby on Rails, you can take advantage of Active Support's [`Enumerable#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) method:

```
def totals
  @data.sum {|_,v| v['totals'].to_i }
end
```

Comment: Accept for better API reference and mentioning ActiveSupport over Nermin who was 6 seconds faster! Tough call!

Comment: what is `|_,v|`, some convention that this is hash but the key is not used?

Comment: @mahatmanich yeap, in block you use `_` notation for unused variables

Comment: It's a bit more than "typically", actually, there's even some knowledge of it built into the language: unused local variables trigger a warning, but for variables starting with `_`, this warning is suppressed. Also, using the same variable multiple times as a parameter or target of an assignment may generate a warning, again, if the name is `_` that warning is suppressed.

Answer (score 4):

Use `inject`:

```
def totals
  @data.inject(0) do |t, (_, v)|
    t + v['totals'].to_i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Enumerable sum](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum)

```
def totals
  @data.sum { |_,v| v['totals'].to_i }
end
```

You can also have start value different from 0

```
def totals(start_value= 0)
  @data.sum(start_value) { |_,v| v['totals'].to_i }
end
```

Comment: The official documentation can be found at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum

Comment: There is no need for "**Edit:**". Moreover, I don't think the subject of the edit really adds anything useful. Simply giving the reference for the doc--which covers that and is helpful in itself--would be enough.

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 5, you can take some advantage of [`Enumerable#pluck`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#pluck)

```
h.values.pluck(:totals).map(&:to_i).sum
```

Comment: On the downside, this creates three temporary arrays, but on the upside it reads exceedingly well and, by having multiple simple steps, it facilitates testing. It seems to me that if `h` is not large, there is much merit in this approach.

Comment: didn't know you could use `pluck` with objects other, that AR. nice, +1

Answer (score 3):

```
@data.map{ |_, v| v['totals'].to_i }.inject(:+)
```

or even shorter:

```
@data.map{ |_, v| v['totals'].to_i }.sum
```

Comment: does not seem to work. It is a hash of hashes  { type: { items: [], totals: XYX } }

Comment: @mahatmanich oh ok, my misunderstanding. edited the answer accordingly

Comment: don't forget to suggest using `reduce` alias of `inject`

Comment: since `inject` came from SmallTalk and not common for different modern languages